# Bash script errors with setting into variable to be executed script paths

Tags: bash

I have the following script:
https://gist.github.com/pc-magas/37ec5e668c12017eb32aa308a0cb8f35

And on the execution I have these error messages:

```
./scripts/install2.sh: line 84: /home/pcmagas/Kwdikas/Docker/ellakcy/scripts/../start.sh: Permission denied
./scripts/install2.sh: line 87: /home/pcmagas/Kwdikas/Docker/ellakcy/scripts/../stop.sh: Permission denied
./scripts/install2.sh: line 89: ${STARTUP_SCRIPT_PATH}: ambiguous redirect
chmod: missing operand after 'u+x'
Try 'chmod --help' for more information.

Startup script generated
./scripts/install2.sh: line 94: ${STOP_SCRIPT_PATH}: ambiguous redirect
chmod: missing operand after 'u+x'
Try 'chmod --help' for more information.
```

The source of the errors are these lines of script:

```
touch "${SCRIPT_PATH}/start.sh"
STARTUP_SCRIPT_PATH= "${SCRIPT_PATH}/start.sh"

touch "${SCRIPT_PATH}/stop.sh"
STOP_SCRIPT_PATH= "${SCRIPT_PATH}/stop.sh"
```

What I want/try to do is my script by given some parameters to auto-generate scripts in order to start and stop some docker container services.

But somehow the plan backfires to me right now.

May I have some help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `sudo` to get permission to write the script files, and there were spaces between the variable name and value; there must not be any spaces around the `=` signs:

```
sudo touch "${SCRIPT_PATH}/start.sh"
STARTUP_SCRIPT_PATH="${SCRIPT_PATH}/start.sh"  # Note no spaces ..PATH="${..

sudo touch "${SCRIPT_PATH}/stop.sh"
STOP_SCRIPT_PATH="${SCRIPT_PATH}/stop.sh" # Again here.
```

Comment: Worked without sudo. It was jjust a space issue. (Sometimes when developing on  languages like php and js you forget about not too use space on bash script.)

Comment: @DimitriosDesyllas Bash is the source of all my woes